# Windows PE (Win10) access denied to fileserver

Tags: windows, samba, pxe, windows-pe

I want to install Windows over the network using PXE. I made the winpe iso, but when I try to access a mounted drive I get "Access Denied"

This is my start.cmd script for win pe:

```
wpeinit
startnet
echo "net use I: \\seedbox\win10 /user:seedbox\sambausername sambapassword"
cmd.exe
pause
```

I mount my share like so:

```
net use I: \\seedbox\win10 /user:seedbox\sambausername sambapassword
```

When I try to go into I: I get "Access denied." The share works on other Windows computers. The same thing happens with a share where guest are allowed full privileges. Also, when I try to "net use" in the start.cmd the pc hangs on bootup (that's why I echoed that)

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission error with the specific samba user. Don't know where it went wrong but created a new samba user and everything behaves like it should now.

However, I still cannot use "net use" in the startup script as it will cause a reboot.

For now with echo it works okay though

Comment: Username and password must be provided on the same line.  You also have a typo